# Modify Modulo in SQL

Tags: sql, modulo

I have the following SQL which generates Insert statements as shown below.

I have a total of 6854 rows in my #order_ids table, however I cannot find a way to include all of them into the insert statements below.

The Inserts will give me a total of 6355 total ids. The modulo is in batches of 500, since I have a lot of rows, and my Insert statement would be huge if I was to insert each id individually.

It doesn't have to be in batches of 500 though it can be more or less, as long as we are not inserting into the table one by one.

**SQL query**

```
declare @total int, @current int, @print varchar(max)

select @total = COUNT(*) from #order_Ids 
set @current = 1

while @current <= @total
BEGIN
    IF @current % 500 = 0
    BEGIN 
        print @print
        print 'insert into #Orders_table values'
        select @print = value from #order_Ids where roworder = @current
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        set @print = @print  + (select  ', ' + value from #order_Ids where roworder = @current)
    END
    set @current = @current + 1
END
print @print
```

**Desired result set**

```
insert into #ORDER_IDS values
('ASC'), ('RFE'), ('ASW'), ('QWS'), ('ZAX'), ('LTY').........(500 VALUES IN TOTAL)
insert into #ORDER_IDS values
('YUR'), ('AWE'), ('VBN'), ('KIJ'), ('LOK'), ('PLP').........(500 VALUES IN TOTAL)
insert into #ORDER_IDS values
('BNV'), ('XCD'), ('GFG'), ('YHY'), ('IKI'), ('AAA')
insert into #ORDER_IDS values
ETC
UNTIL ALL 6854 VALUES ARE INCLUDED IN THE INSERT STATEMENTS.
```

Comment: So what exactly is the problem? What is your code doing differently than you want?

Comment: Hi! The issue is that for some reason the code prints only a total of 6355 values. However my table has a total of 6854 values, and I need all of them to be included in the Insert statements. Does that make sense? Thanks for responding!

Comment: Take note that `PRINT` only displays the first 8000 characters.

Comment: It's interesting that the missing # is 499, which is 1 short of your 500 modulo.

Comment: It is 499, indeed. How can I fix it? Please let me know!

Comment: Also, you are setting @total to the `count(*)` of records in #order_Ids, but you are qualifying `roworder = @current`.  Are all of the values for `roworder` consecutive integers?  Or perhaps are 499 of them > than the count of the records?  What is `select max(roworder) from #order_Ids`?

Comment: Hey James, all values of roworder are consecutive integers, ranging from 1 to 6854.Hope that answered your question.

Comment: Is this what you meant? It just prints another insert statement . Let me know if I misunderstood.                                                                                            END
print 'insert into #Orders_table values' 
print @print

Comment: It is very hard to see what is wrong without a complete working example.  I will create one and see if it helps discover the problem.

Comment: Thanks so much! Looking forward to your response.

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working (fixed) example.  The first pass through your `while` loop, `@print` was `NULL`, which means the first set of 500 were skipped.  So you need to:

1. add a `print 'insert into ...'` just before the `while` statement
2. initialize `@print` to be a non-null value before you start (like where `id = 1`)
3. start `@current` at `2`, so you don't include the first value twice

Here is the query:

```
set nocount on

declare @data table (id int, val char(8))

insert into @data values
( 1, '(''ABC'')'), ( 2, '(''BCD'')'), ( 3, '(''CDE'')'), ( 4, '(''DEF'')'), ( 5, '(''EFG'')'),
( 6, '(''FGH'')'), ( 7, '(''GHI'')'), ( 8, '(''HIJ'')'), ( 9, '(''IJK'')'), (10, '(''JKL'')'),
(11, '(''KLM'')'), (12, '(''LMN'')'), (13, '(''MNO'')'), (14, '(''NOP'')'), (15, '(''OPQ'')'),
(16, '(''PQR'')'), (17, '(''QRS'')'), (18, '(''RST'')'), (19, '(''STU'')'), (20, '(''TUV'')'),
(21, '(''UVW'')'), (22, '(''VWX'')'), (23, '(''WXY'')'), (24, '(''XYZ'')')

declare @total int, @current int, @print varchar(max)

select @total = count(*) from @data
select @print = val from @data where id = 1
set @current = 2

print 'insert into #some_table values'
while @current <= @total
begin
  if @current % 3 = 0
  begin
    print @print
    print 'insert into #some_table values'
    select @print = val from @data where id = @current
  end
  else
  begin
    set @print = @print + (select ', ' + val from @data where id = @current)
  end
  set @current = @current + 1
end
print @print
```

Here is the output:

```
insert into #some_table values
('ABC') , ('BCD') 
insert into #some_table values
('CDE') , ('DEF') , ('EFG') 
insert into #some_table values
('FGH') , ('GHI') , ('HIJ') 
insert into #some_table values
('IJK') , ('JKL') , ('KLM') 
insert into #some_table values
('LMN') , ('MNO') , ('NOP') 
insert into #some_table values
('OPQ') , ('PQR') , ('QRS') 
insert into #some_table values
('RST') , ('STU') , ('TUV') 
insert into #some_table values
('UVW') , ('VWX') , ('WXY') 
insert into #some_table values
('XYZ')
```

Comment: James! That solved it! Thank you so much for your help! I truly appreciate it! :)